# Мой .ехе ничего не открывает

Tags: c, windows, winapi

[Вот здесь](https://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=208850) прочитал, как в .exe на си записывать, чтобы конкретный файл открывался конкретной прогрой. Файл .exe, полученный из кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

main()
{
ShellExecute(0, "Explore", "c:\\Program 
Files", NULL, NULL,SW_RESTORE);
}
```

, выполняет то, что от него требуется. Так почему тогда это не делает файл .exe, полученный хотя бы из кода

```
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

main()
{
ShellExecute(0, "notepad", "c:\\2.txt", 
NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
}
```

? Компилируется без ошибки, открытие полученного .ехе не вызывает ошибки. Почему при этом никакого текстового файла не открывается? Или это мой портабельный компилятор глючный?

Comment: *"это мой портабельный компилятор глючный?"* Просто как совет - грешить на компилятор [**в самом последнем случае**](https://habr.com/ru/post/440602/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто нужно внимательно читать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea)...

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "notepad","c:\\2.txt",
             NULL, SW_RESTORE);
```

Можно и так -

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "c:\\2.txt",
             NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
```

тогда файл откроется приложением, ассоциированным с данным расширением.

Comment: Harry, большое спасибо за ответ. И спасибо за ссылку на документацию. А то я блоги да блоги читал, а официального не попадалось. Но все-таки я думаю, что я имел право грешить на компилятор: он у меня портабельный вместо желательно установленного и в работе я его еще толком не видел. А терять время на глючное ПО тоже не очень хотся).

Comment: Ну, MSDN - это самый первый и главный источник информации на такие темы... А если ответ устроил - закрывайте вопрос, нажав "птичку" рядом с ответом.

Comment: Птичку жалко)).

Comment: А что, нажать птичку может только ТС?

Comment: Естественно, вы же задали вопрос - вы и решаете, устраивает ли ответ или нет :)

Comment: Ясно. Не, ну, я вчера отметил, что ответ полезен (это же при этом вам, Harry, репа начислилась, верно?) А про птичку не знал. И мне за что-то 7 реп добавили и 3 значка. Вроде, ничего не сделал.

Comment: Harry, слушайте, вот я смотрю данную вам ссылку. Там же нет такого значения INT, чтобы запускать приложение в фоновом режиме?

Comment: `SW_HIDE` или `SW_MINIMIZE` не годится?

Comment: Harry, да я тоже на это клюнул, но почему-то в обоих случаях выскакивает черное окно командной строки.

Comment: Покажите точный код, и как вы запускаете (из среды, из командной строки).

Comment: А выкладывать в ответе или в комменте? А то ведь будет код.

Comment: Ну выложите где-нибудь на http://vpaste.net/, и бросьте в коммент ссылку - просто посмотреть, что у вас происходит.

Comment: Боюсь, как есть вы его не сможете проверить. Вот он: http://vpaste.net/XX0Aw ; lyxOtkBezPar.bat: http://vpaste.net/tvUDU ; lyxOtkBezPar.js: http://vpaste.net/uapLj : lyxOtkSPar.bat: http://vpaste.net/Wj2IG ; lyxOtkSPar.js: http://vpaste.net/mjmFl . Пользуюсь, как и задумывал: закрепил на панели задач, туда файлы понакреплял и открываю с параметрами и без.

Comment: Мда, несколько запутанно... Простите уж, копаться таки не стану. Извините, что обнадежил. Но есть у меня подозрение, что это XY-проблема - т.е. что вы выбрали не тот путь решения своей сверхзадачи.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97310/discussion-between-mathem-and-harry).