# Суперпозиция скриптов

Tags: любой-язык

В языках программирования, в частности, в Си, такой подход применим?

---

В Инете везде (по крайней мере, где я видел) в примерах Си обращение к параметрам полученного .ехе дано в цикле, я поднапрягся и получил без цикла:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
     printf("Argument %d: %s\n", 2, argv[2]);         
     return 0;

 }
}
```

С другой стороны, @Harry вот в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009796/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82) приводит такой код:

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "notepad","c:\\2.txt",
         NULL, SW_RESTORE);
```

Если неукоснительно распространять принцип суперпозиции на скрипты, то следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
     //printf("Argument %d: %s\n", 2, argv[2]);   
     ShellExecute(0, "open", "winword", 1, argv[1], NULL, SW_RESTORE);      
     if(argc == 1) {
             printf("Command line has no additional arguments\n");
     return 0;

      }

    }
```

Должен выдавать работоспособное .ехе со стопроцентной гарантией. Ну, чем не суперпозиция скриптов? При этом мне абсолютно все равно (пока), что означает 1 перед аргументом в этом скрипте (и в первом): важно, что 1 есть в первом скрипте. Но... Увы и ах: компиляция этого кода проходит с ошибкой, файла .ехе не образуется. Значит, суперпозиция, во всяком случае, беспрекословная, неприменима для скриптов - но ведь это бред какой-то, все должно быть до абсолютного уровня!!!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97029/discussion-on-question-by-mathem--).

Comment: «'ShellExecute' was not declared in this scope» — что и требовалось доказать, вы просто-напросто забыли подключить заголовочные файлы Windows API вместе с функцией ShellExecute внутри, и всякие «суперпозиции» здесь абсолютно ни при чём. Изучайте язык программирования Си и читайте документацию по Windows API, а приплетать математику куда попало не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Модераторы меня покарают, но я не удержался...*

> Суперпозиция скриптов

Такого понятия в программировании - нет. Предположу, что речь идет о [композиции функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

> В языках программирования, в частности, в Си, такой подход применим?

Да, применим.

> в примерах Си обращение к параметрам полученного .ехе дано в цикле

1. Обращение к параметрам командной строки (вызова). Это параметры **вызова** `.exe`, а не самого `.exe`.
2. В цикле они, т.к. кол-во параметров бываем разным.

> я поднапрягся и получил без цикла.

Прочитайте учебник по азам программирования, чтоб такие вещи больше не *напрягали*.

Рабочий вариант вашего кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
     printf("Argument %d: %s\n", 2, argv[2]);         
     return 0;
}
```

> @Harry вот в этой теме приводит такой код:

Это пример вызова функции (кусок рабочего кода).

> Если неукоснительно распространять принцип суперпозиции на скрипты

1. Скрипт - файл сценария, написанный на интерпретируемом языке программирования. С++ - компилируемый язык. Вы программу, а не скрипт пишете.
2. В программировании вы легко можете нарушить принцип композиции функций. Вызывающая функция может игнорировать результат вызываемой, вызываемая функция может не возвращать результат.
3. Более того, функции в программировании не всегда изолированы.
4. И напоследок, кроме функций в программировании есть и другие объекты. Часть из них можно инкапсулировать в функции, а часть придется доработать/перенести.

> то следующий код: Должен выдавать работоспособное .ехе со стопроцентной гарантией.

1. Т.е. если я напишу математическую функцию с ошибками, то апеллировать мне нужно к ошибкам в фундаментальных законах математики?
2. Если я сложение выполняю раньше деления и моя задача не находит решения, то это математика не работает, или это я считать не умею?
3. 100% гарантия возможна только в идеальном мире.

> Ну, чем не суперпозиция скриптов?

Собственно ничем. Если я возьму кусок одной рабочей функции, засуну ее в кусок другой рабочей функции, да еще и коэффициенты там поменяю, то я гарантировано получу осмысленный результат?

> При этом мне абсолютно все равно (пока), что означает 1 перед аргументом в этом скрипте (и в первом): важно, что 1 есть в первом скрипте.

Вам, может и "все равно", а вот компилятору - нет. `ShellExecute` принимает определенное кол-во параметров в определенной последовательности. И компилятор ожидает получить именно их.

> компиляция этого кода проходит с ошибкой

Очевидно, ведь программа написана не правильно.

> файла .ехе не образуется

Очевидно, если работа компилятора завершилась ошибкой.

> Значит, суперпозиция, во всяком случае, беспрекословная, неприменима для скриптов

Если я не правильно решил уравнение, то виновата - математика, очевидно.

> но ведь это бред какой-то

Согласен.

> все должно быть до абсолютного уровня!!!

Что "все"? Кому "должно"? "абсолютного уровня" - это какого?

Рабочий вариант вашего кода (должен быть, Windows нет, т.ч. не могу проверить):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    //printf("Argument %d: %s\n", 2, argv[2]);   
    ShellExecute(0, "open", "winword", argv[1], NULL, SW_RESTORE);      
    if(argc == 1) {
        printf("Command line has no additional arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не поверите, но я минуты 3 назад получил точно такой же код, он работает, из чего я могу сделать вывод, что 1 относится к команде printf. Верно? И тогда все сходится. Пока писал, все устарело (3 мин.)

Comment: 1 тут вообще ни к чему не относится.

Comment: 1 я взял, например, отсюда: https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8 и подумал, что оно относится к argv[i]

Comment: >  Если я возьму кусок одной рабочей функции, засуну ее в кусок другой рабочей функции, да еще и коэффициенты там поменяю, то я гарантировано получу осмысленный результат? - зависит от преследуемой вами цели. Если вы хотите, там, "чайнику и лоху, туды-сюды" вроде меня показать всю глубину ошибочности его взглядов, то вы, естесно, подберете такой пример.

Comment: Повторяю. Прочитайте **книгу** по азам программирования. Ваша проблема не в конкретном коде, а в *ходе мыслей*. Вы берете неизвестно что, вставляете непонятно куда, основываясь не на решении задачи, а на том, что кто-то где-то написал. Вы математику ведь по учебнику сначала изучали, а не по обрывкам записей старшеклассников?

Comment: Что бы вы посоветовали?

Comment: Что программировать собираетесь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97034/discussion-between-mathem-and-anton-abrosimov).